# jupyter run produces invalid JSON with single quotes

Tags: python, json, jupyter

I have a simple jupyter notebook file (`Untitled.ipynb`) that starts:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {},
```

and I want to run it and convert the runned version to PDF. Step 1, run:

```
jupyter run Untitled.ipynb > U-Run.ipynb
```

and that gets me something that uses single quotes everywhere which `jupyter nbconvert` barfs on:

```
$ head U-Run.ipynb 
{'cells': [{'cell_type': 'code',
   'execution_count': 1,
   'metadata': {},
   'outputs': [{'name': 'stdout', 'output_type': 'stream', 'text': ['3\n']}],
```

and when I try and convert to PDF:

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --to pdf U-Run.ipynb 
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook U-Run.ipynb to pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nbformat/reader.py", line 14, in parse_json
    nb_dict = json.loads(s, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

then a traceback that ends:

```
nbformat.reader.NotJSONError: Notebook does not appear to be JSON: '{\'cells\': [{\'cell_type\': \'code\',\...
```

If I import `json` from a plain python session and try a simple test I get double quotes:

```
>>> json.dumps(dict(a=1))
'{"a": 1}'
```

so I don't understand why `jupyter run` is outputting single-quoted "json".

Versions of all the things are:

```
$ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.3.0
qtconsole        : 5.0.3
ipython          : 7.29.0
ipykernel        : 6.5.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.0
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 5.1.1

Python: 3.8.10
Ubuntu 20.04
```

Comment: I see no reference to JSON at all in your problem code.  You're just dumping a Python dictionary, in Python syntax of course.

Comment: @jasonharper What problem code? There's no code that would dump _any_ dictionary here that I can see (though it is clear that that's what's being output by _something_.)

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the output of `jupyter-run`. I was expecting a JSON notebook file, the run version of the input.

Comment: I assume `jupyter run Untitled.ipynb` would modify `Untitled.ipynb` in-place with all the output cells. Is this not the case?

Comment: @OneCricketeer [Given the implementation, I doubt it ](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/blob/10decd25308c306b6005cbf271b96493824a83e8/jupyter_client/runapp.py#L105-L107)

Comment: @OneCricketeer nope. but actually the output doesn't seem to be what I'd expect from running the notebook either. Is it just printing the python repr of the notebook? Huh?

Comment: Solved. `jupyter run` (it seems) really wants to talk to a server, and the text is (probably) the Python dump of the notebook for that server. I just had to clean up a lot of detached python processes (because there was no server to talk to). Anyway, `jupyter nbconvert --execute` does what I want, which is to re-run the notebook to see if I get the same output as the student submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html), you can also tell `nbconvert` to `--execute`:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --execute U-Run.ipynb
```

You can also use [`papermill`](https://github.com/nteract/papermill#execute-via-cli) to execute an ipynb file, then convert the output to PDF:

```
papermill U-Run.ipynb U-Run-2.ipynb 
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf U-Run-2.ipynb
```

Comment: Is this really needed, though? [The docs](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/running.html#using-a-command-line-interface) say papermill is only needed for "more sophisticated options"

Comment: While papermill is a great tool for related endeavors (mainly parameterizing the notebook and then using command line to run it), in this case you could just run the notebook on the command line [using nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-as-a-command-line-tool) or [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html). Point being, I (and it seems @AKX) don't see why you had `jupyter run` in there in the first place.

Comment: I want to re-run the code chunks - this is a reproducibility exercise for student notebook submissions.

Comment: ah... nbconvert with --execute? Is that what I need and not "run"?

Comment: Yeah, just found out that nbconvert execute doc too. Added to post.

Comment: So you know, there's some stuff for grading notebooks already out there. I'd suggest looking [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/live-tutorials-with-jupyter/4176?u=fomightez) and searching the Jupyter Discourse forum for 'nbgrader'. You'll likely turn up helpful discussions.

Comment: I think my "jupyter run" is outputing a Python object dump which is probably something it really wants to send to a jupyter lab server. The docs aren't clear. nbconvert with --execute does what I want so accepted.